# How can I have 2 loops display information in-between each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 input fields generated from 2 different hashes.

```
table_head = {"key1"=>"thead1", "key2"=>"thead2", "key3"=>"thead3", "key4"=>"thead4"}

table_content = {"1"=>"column1", "2"=>"column2", "3"=>"column3", "4"=>"column4"}

 <%= form_for([@category, @page], url: update_pages_path) do |f| %>

    <% @page.table_head.each_with_index do |(key, value), i| %>
      <%= text_field_tag ('header[' + i.to_s + ']'), value %> 
    <% end%>


    <% @page.table_content.each_with_index do |(key, value), i| %>
      <%= select_tag 'content[' + i.to_s + ']', options_for_select(@category_keys, value), { :multiple => true, :size => 3}  %>
    <% end%>


 <% end %>
```

This makes 4 `table_head` inputs and 4 `table_content` selects. But I need them to be ordered, table head input, then table content select, then table head input, content select and so on. Not as all table head inputs and then all table content selects.

I could do this for the fields

```
 <% @page.table_head.each_with_index do |(key, value), i| %>
  <%= text_field_tag ('header[' + i.to_s + ']'), value %> 
  <%= select_tag 'content[' + i.to_s + ']', options_for_select(@category_keys), { :multiple => true, :size => 3}  %>
 <% end%>
```

But then the default `options_for_select` `value` cant be put in for the content field.

How can I have the fields be ordered head, content, head, content etc.. insead of head, head, head, head, content, content etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table_head = {"key1"=>"thead1", "key2"=>"thead2", "key3"=>"thead3", "key4"=>"thead4"}

table_content = {"1"=>"column1", "2"=>"column2", "3"=>"column3", "4"=>"column4"}

<%= form_for([@category, @page], url: update_pages_path) do |f| %>
  <% @page.table_head.zip(@page.table_content).each do |head, content| %>
    <% head_key, head_value = head %>
    <% content_key, content_value = content %>
    <%= text_field_tag ('header[' + head_key + ']'), head_value %> 
    <%= select_tag 'content[' + content_key + ']', options_for_select(@category_keys, content_value), { :multiple => true, :size => 3}  %>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How would I apply this to the form?

Comment: like this @user3234020

Comment: Was literally about to be a bit more specific and ask how I can use `.zip` to access each hash value individually not as a whole hash. Ill give your updated answer a go.